# Getting this error AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python

```
def clean_arf(input_file_path):
    tree = et.parse(input_file_path)
    root = tree.getroot()
    
    for monitoredAction in root.xpath('//AgentRecordingFile//MonitoredActions//MonitoredAction'):

        application = monitoredAction.find('.//Application')
        elementName = monitoredAction.find('.//ElementName')
        elementType = monitoredAction.find('.//ElementType')
        action = monitoredAction.find('.//Action')
        baseUrl =  monitoredAction.find('.//BaseURL')
        windowTitle = monitoredAction.find('.//WindowTitle')
        isRemove = False
     
        # Applying condition 1
                
        if((application.text != None) and (elementName.text != None)):
            if (application.text.lower() in ('iexplorer','chrome','msedge') and (elementType.text.lower() == 'client')):
              isRemove = True
        else:
            pass
```

Error :

```
AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'")
```

Change this xpath

```
root.xpath('//AgentRecordingFile//MonitoredActions//MonitoredAction'):
```

as

```
root.xpath('//MonitoredActions//MonitoredAction'):
```

get final output but same time data cleaning is not happing

Comment: issue is the `application` is not actually found, and is null

Comment: check the type of `application.text` and `elementType.text` to see if both are string since lower is a string method

Answer (score 1):

Your code is checking for `application.text != None` and `elementName.text != None`, in line 17 but one line below that you are using `elementType.text.lower()` without testing if elementType.text is actually present. I assume that this is a copy & paste issue, and you actually wanted to test `elementType.text != None` in line 17.

BTW, a more common ("pythonic") idiom is to use `application.text is not None` instead of `application.text != None`, but the differences are mostly stylistic. Also, you can use the fact, that `None` and empty strings (as well as 0 and empty lists) are treated as `False` in your test.

A common way to write your code would be:

`if application.text and application.text.lower() in ('iexplorer','chrome','msedge') and elementType.text and elementType.text.lower() == 'client':`

Comment: only on if condition is sufficient.

Comment: if application.text and application.text.lower() in ('iexplorer','chrome','msedge') and elementType.text and elementType.text.lower() == 'client':
              isRemove = True
        else:
            pass                                                                                                                                        This is correct?

Comment: else:
        pass
is valid Python, but unnecessary. The `pass` keyword is typically used to indicate that "do nothing" here is intended, typically in `except:` blocks or something similar. However, the `else:` block can be omitted anyways, so there is no need to do that. A good idea for an else-block with `pass` is to document that there is something missing here:

    if condition:
        doSomething()
    else:
        pass # TODO: do something else